# Issues displaying text over transparency (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, transparency

I'm working on a website with bootstrap which is basically made of an orange background and some transparent black containers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9G5O.png

As you can see, the font displayed in the transparent boxes looks bad. I'm using Tahoma, but this happens with every font i try.

Is there any way to improve such text?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tahoma is a Windows-Font, so it will probably use Arial on other Browsers.

It also seems like the screenshot you provided came from Internet Explorer, which has a very bad render engine for text. (try chrome/firefox/safari)

I also read somewhere that you could try enabling ClearType in the Windows-Settings, but there is no way to enforce that from the browser level.

You could also have javascript [cufon](http://github.com/sorccu/cufon) change every character into an image/canvas and enforce it that way, but that will suck performance and might not be the best solution either.

Usually you will end up using images (png) as menu buttons, if you want to support IE.